# CSS/HTML5 Avoid line break on things such as ":-)"

Tags: css, html

I have strings containing smileys using ascii characters such as `:-)` which I need to display on a web page.

It happens than when the smiley is just at the end of the line it might be split between two lines. I don't want this to happen. I always want the smiley to be displayed as a singular "word" (in that case, the whole smiley would be displayed on the second line).

Could someone please suggest a solution?

## EDIT 1 & 2

As I mentioned in the comment, the idea here is that a collection of punctuation marks is NOT necessarily considered like a word... And that's actually the problem I was facing. So if I had "comment" at the end of my line, this word wouldn't be split but if you have ";.!,;:" then this would.

In addition the answer you point to do not suggest the solution `word-break: keep-all` which is the one I used. Thus I believe this complementary and different.

Comment: I thought about that but it seems like it would break the word because it was made of punctuation marks, and I wouldn't expect this to be treated as a world but to be be broken down/split. But I will try...

Comment: The linked "duplicate" question has nothing to do with this one. This is about word breaking. The other is about line breaking. This should be reopened.

Comment: @bearfriend What is the difference? Isn’t it both about breaking a word when it gets on the border of a line?

Comment: No. One is about preventing entire blocks of text from wrapping to multiple lines, the other is about preventing individual words from being split between lines.

Comment: @bearfriend I see. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually probably want: `word-wrap: break-word`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with white-space: nowrap

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Other alternatives like old nowrap for tables described here [Attribute 'nowrap' is considered outdated. A newer construct is recommended. What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446639/attribute-nowrap-is-considered-outdated-a-newer-construct-is-recommended-wha)

Answer (score 1):

A simple `white-space: nowrap` should do the work.

Just wrap your smiley in a span with a class : `.nowrap` and declare the property to that class.